# Testing smart tv applications

Tags: automation

Is there a way to launch Selenium automated tests on a Smart TV web browser? I'm facing a problem to test the smart tv application. I have a set of automated tests (java + selenium) that I would like to launch on a Samsung smart TV web browser. Did anyone have practical experience launching such kind of testing?